# How should I set this up for a working package?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm barely out of infancy in python and trying to figure out how to package a few of my tools for distributing, and having a hard time understanding the documentation.

After reading the docs, I have a package structure that looks like this:

```
/UTM (git repo)
    /utmizer
        /raster
            raster.py
        __init__.py
        convert.py
        LICENSE
        README.md
        setup.py
        utmize.py
```

The `__init__.py` looks like this because I'm not sure what I'm doing:

```
import utmizer.utmize as utmize
from utmizer.raster import raster
from .convert import Converter
```

My import statements throughout look like this:

`convert.py`

```
import fiona
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import os
import re

from raster import raster
```

`utmize.py`

```
from utmizer.convert import Converter
import getopt
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
```

And finally, the `setup.py` looks like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import setuptools
from setuptools import find_packages


VERSION = '0.0.1'
HERE = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()


long_description = (HERE / 'README.md').read_text(encoding='utf-8')


setuptools.setup(
    name='utmizer',
    version=VERSION,
    author='username',
    author_email='my@email.com',
    description='Automatic projection of data to appropriate UTM zone',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='https://github.com/username/UTM',
    install_requires=find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3"
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.8, <4',
)
```

When I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, it completes; but when I install it in a new conda instance and attempt to `import utmizer` it throws a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things:

- Move `setup.py` `LICENSE` and `README.md` to the root directory of your project (git repository), outside of the actual top-level importable packages.
- Add a package initializer `__init__.py` in `utmizer/raster`, and any other importable package and sub-package.

So you should get a directory tree like this:

```
/UTM (git repo)
    setup.py
    LICENSE
    README.md
    /utmizer
        /raster
            __init__.py
            raster.py
        __init__.py
        convert.py
        utmize.py
```

Seems like you mixed up `packages` and `install_requires` in your `setup.py`. Not sure exactly what you need in `install_requires`, but I guess at least `geopandas` and `fiona`.

Also no need to restrict to Python `<4`, because no one knows if it will be indeed incompatible. As a rule, you should only add restrictions for things you know for sure are not compatible at the time of writing (no one can guess the future).

```
from pathlib import Path
import setuptools

VERSION = '0.0.1'
HERE = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()

long_description = (HERE / 'README.md').read_text(encoding='utf-8')

setuptools.setup(
    name='utmizer',
    version=VERSION,
    author='username',
    author_email='my@email.com',
    description='Automatic projection of data to appropriate UTM zone',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='https://github.com/username/UTM',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'fiona',
        'geopandas',
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3"
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.8',
)
```

You probably can leave the `__init__.py` files empty.

In general you should always use absolute imports starting from the top-level importable packages (or modules). In your case there is is only one top-level importable package `utmizer` (and no top-level importable module).

So in `utmizer/convert.py`:

```
import fiona
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import os
import re

from utmizer.raster import raster
```

And `utmizer/utmize.py` seems already correct.

Comment: @auslander I did not test this, just wrote off the top of my head. If you get a chance to test this and there are issue, let me know and I will try my best to fix.

Comment: I'll give this a shot today and report back! Thanks for the incredibly thorough answer, I'll bookmark this and refer to it often.

Comment: Sorry for the lag on this but wanted to let you know it worked, thanks!